# How do I fix SVN 'Working copy text base is corrupt'?

Tags: svn, repository

After many happy commits to my svn repo, all of the sudden the relationship went sour...svn flipped her lid and yelled: "**Working copy text base is corrupt!**"

What could have caused this? How do I fix it?

```
Working copy text base is corrupt
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Checksum mismatch for '~/blah/.svn/text-  base/sumonet.py.svn-base'; expected: '548b9bb4b24bc580ab8694c583b28013', actual: '8b2b3cf4615de3d8520ae4841b3b0a8b'
```

Comment: i have renamed file in my folder, then clicked "UPDATE" button (so, deleted the file from SVN),  then renamed back and commited that file, like a new one.

Comment: In my case this situation was caused by a false positive from an antivirus program which silently removed an "infected" executable I had compiled.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This was the error.

```
svn: E155017: Working copy text base is corrupt
svn: E200014: Checksum mismatch for text base of : '/home/.../exampleFileCorrupted.cpp'
....
```

***CLEAR SOLUTION WHICH WORKED FOR ME SMOOTHLY:***

*ATTENTION:* **Copy your file in another file outside of the SVN environment.**

```
cp exampleFileCorrupted.cpp ~/Desktop/
```

then follow below:

1. **cd to the path in which you have the corrupted file** 
   (which is the one indicated after: *Checksum mismatch for text base of*)
2. svn rm --force exampleFileCorrupted.cpp

   You will see : D         exampleFileCorrupted.cpp
3. **Copy the file you saved before the point 1 in the SVN folder you are in** with :

   `cp ~/Desktop/exampleFileCorrupted.cpp .`

(Don't miss the point at the end which means 'copy here')

4. **Add to svn** with : `svn add exampleFileCorrupted.cpp`

   You will see : A         exampleFileCorrupted.cpp
5. **Commit changes**: `svn commit -m "Commit Message"`

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Upvote because this works and is a clearly better solution than either of the higher ranked answers. It's annoying to have to blow away a repo directory and start over because of problems like this, so the accepted answer is actually a terrible "solution." So this answer is better and you end up with one commit only, just as if nothing ever went wrong.

Comment: Try: "svn delete --force exampleFileCorrupted.cpp" if "rm" doesn't work.

Comment: Worked for me! Great solution.

Answer (score 28):

This works for me:

```
svn rm --keep-local THE_CORRUPTED_FILE
svn add THE_CORRUPTED_FILE
svn ci
```

Comment: Simple and effective, should be the top answer

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that the file will have the special property - "Replacing". It's status won't be just "Modified", instead it will be "replaced".

Comment: this should be the top answer by far.

Comment: Does this deletes change history?

Comment: Yup, definitely a great answer

Answer (score 16):

Just make a separate fresh checkout and copy the changes you made in that old working copy to the new one.

Comment: This kind of thing makes me want to leave svn behind and move to mercurial or git.

Comment: Checking out a fresh copy and then overwriting the corrupt file (*.svn-base) with the one I just checked out worked as well.

Comment: if you have many changed files you can rsync from the old working copy/ backup locataion: rsync -av --delete-during --exclude ".svn" <backup location> .

Comment: This kind of thing is why I left svn behind and moved to git.

Comment: That's overkill for a big repo or many changes. All you have to do is make a copy the affected file, then svn --force delete the affected file, commit, svn add the copy, commit, done. See other responses for exact steps.

Comment: n13, a beautiful solution. One thing to add: you don't have to commit the deleted file. cp file file2; svn rm file --force; cp file2 file; svn add file; works ass well (I used MacOS Bash subversion 1.8)

Comment: To be fair, this is the first time in 15 years of using SVN that I've run into a corrupt copy and I'm sure git or mercurial can get corrupted as well.

Answer (score 16):

1. Copy problematic file in other place,
2. Delete and commit file in repository,
3. Copy your file into SVN and commit

Comment: This didn't fix it for me, I had to replace the subversion pristine file. (see my and @siddhadev answers)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  I tried the others to no avail.

Comment: @MichaelEakins I second that, that was one nasty error. I've only ever used Surround and TFS seriously and they both seem better than SVN.

Comment: Did not work me. Reverting the problematic file and committing works. But once I copy back the problematic file and try to commit again, the same error is thrown again.

Comment: @tanayamitshah if this is text file, may try to copy only the contents of the file (ctrl+c, ctrl+v)

Comment: Strongly recommend against using this method to fix a client-side issue. This changes the file on the server and essentially breaks the history. Features like 'svn annotate' will now list you as the last author for every line.

Answer (score 7):

With newer subversion versions there is no `.svn/text-base/` directory. The `.svn` is stored at the working root under `.svn/pristine` and the error message looks like this:

```
Sending        README
Transmitting file data .svn: E155017: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155017: Working copy text base is corrupt
svn: E200014: Checksum mismatch for text base of '/home/user/tmp/svntest/README':
   expected:  1f9167bc01e5bc9bfcb928ff03d6700a
     actual:  e0a1692ff5cab91e3e3a0d02dabe0251

svn: E200003: Delta source ended unexpectedly
```

You could fix it by using the bash script at https://gist.github.com/siddhadev/5814802.
It will replace the corrupted svn-base file with a fresh one.

Answer (score 3):

@siddhadev script should work but for those who prefer to do it manually:

1. Export latest revision of the problematic file as `lastworkingrev.txt`
2. Get its sha1 checksum with `sha1sum lastworkingrev.txt`
3. Find the subversion pristine file with `find . -name "SHA1_CHECKSUM.svn-base"` and overwrite it with the content of `lastworkingrev.txt`
4. Commit

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but none of the previous answers helped. In my case, the Subversion repository was at version 1.6, but I had allowed IntelliJ to checkout at version 1.7. There was no indication of a version mismatch other than the "svn: E200014: Base checksum mismatch" error. **Simply checking out a new tree with the correct version fixed the problem.**

Answer (score 1):

Delete Existing copy and take fresh check out your issue will be resolved .

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything above, clean up doesn't work. SVN recommend me to checkout a new copy. But the project is too big, and I have changed too many codes, comparing will cost a lot of time.
Here is the way I solved the problem with every change retains.

1. Delete all the ***.svn*** folders. This folder may exists one or plenty depends on the version of SVN. Just find every single one and delete it.
2. Checkout the working folder. It will alert "not an empty folder", click "yes". Then the working copy is recovered.

Answer (score 1):

I've learned not to trust having my working directory under version control.  When I'm ready to commit, I do a recursive diff and copy the changes into the checked-out directory.  That way, if SVN chokes, all I do is rm -Rf the checkout and do a new checkout, then repeat the copy commands.

I didn't come here looking for a solution.  I came looking for a reason for this flaky behavior and found nothing.  It happens even when I'm the only person using the branch and doing everything from the command line, which I trust more than Eclipse or any other interface.

Answer (score 0):

Do a SVN Cleanup Team->Cleanup.

Comment: Or at the command line, simply 'svn cleanup'.  Unfortunately this did not fix the problem for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem after filtering my dump with https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN

Fixed with removing md5 checksums...

```sh
sed -i '/Text-copy-source-md5/d' eias_only.dmp
```

However, there can possible be some consequences...